# Modulus operator not working with uint_fast64_t

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Consider this very simple program. The aim is to print the last 2 bits (displaying 0,1,2 ou 3), then the next two bits, and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    inline void test(uint_fast64_t k) {
        for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
            cout << k%4 << endl;
            k>>2;
        }
    }
int main() {
    test(77968641563295808);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is a list of 0's (and only 0s) which is absurd.  What could explain that ? Strangely, it seems to work fine with small numbers. Also I cheched that the problem is not in the formatting, I manually compared the consecutive results of k%4 to 0 which always results true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `k` is not updated inside the loop. `k>>2` does not update the value of `k`. If you fix this problem you get the expected result.

Comment: I totally forgot about that, I should have used k>>=2.